# Right-aligned texts ignore multiple trailing spaces

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, text, textflow

I have a Flex text area (spark) that is used for recording rich text. Among other things, the text can be right-aligned, and some customers are using a combination of right-align+lots of spaces to position their text the way they want. While I don't agree to that tactic :) the way it looks on the screen doesn't match the way it's printed - on the screen texts with multiple trailing spaces are showing only one space.

Is there a way to force the TextArea control to show all characters, regardless of any default rules it might have?

Comment: Have you tried converting the spaces to non-breaking spaces? Not sure whether RichText accepts those though. You could also use tabstops. I I don't remember how they work exactly, but I'm sure the concept exists.

Comment: Yep. Same thing. I actually tried all space characters in UTF, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

Cant comment yet, no reputation :(

Can be the font used in the app? There are some fonts that the space are shoooorter than a simple character. Calibri isnt one of it.

Comment: It's not a font problem, if you put a non-space character after a sequence of spaces, they suddenly emerge. It's a problem with the rendering of trailing spaces on right-aligned text, I'm just curious if it can be avoided somehow without having to write my own text rendering engine. :)